# Get last inserts from multiple tables

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

i am trying to build something like an order management tool for a car garage.
The main function of the tool is to manage repair orders and inspection orders as well
Therefore i have created this following three tables.
In the first one you can see the cars and the state of the repair and inspection.
The second one shows the information about the single repair orders the relation between the first and this is 1:n.
The last one shows the automaticly created inspection orders for each car out of the first table. This is an 1:n relation as well.
So what i try to do is to show all the open repair and inspection orders for the cars in one table. But only the open ones.

I tried it with some where statements but i got totaly confused.

My question is, how i can realise it?

```
+------+--------------------------+----------+------------+
| IDWZ | wz_name                  | wz_stand | wz_vistand |
+------+--------------------------+----------+------------+
|    1 | Querbr?cke vorn          |        0 |          0 |
|    2 | Front Lateral Support    |        0 |          1 |
|    3 | Rear Support             |        1 |          1 |
|    4 | MID-X-Member Upper Shell |        1 |          1 |
|    5 | Front Lateral Support    |        1 |          1 |
+------+--------------------------+----------+------------+


    +---------+-----------------+--------------+
    | IDWZTBL | rep_wzrepstatus | rep_wzfehler |
    +---------+-----------------+--------------+
    |       2 |               1 | REP 1        |
    |       1 |               1 | REp2         |
    |       1 |               1 | REp 3 MASS   |
    |       1 |               0 | 444          |
    |       2 |               0 |              |
    +---------+-----------------+--------------+

+--------+-------------+
| VIWZID | vi_repstand |
+--------+-------------+
|      1 |           0 |
+--------+-------------+
```

Comment: This question is very unclear. It's hard to tell how the tables are related to each other. But you probably just need to join all 3 tables, with a `WHERE` clause to filter down to just the open status.

Answer (score 0):

Sry for that!

So the IDWZ is the foreign KEY in the second table(IDWZTBL) and in the third (VIWZID).

I tried it with

```
SELECT wz_name, wz_stand, wz_vistand, rep_wzrepstatus, vi_repstand FROM tbl_wz LEFT JOIN tbl_orders ON tbl_wz.IDWZ = tbl_orders.IDWZTBL LEFT JOIN tbl_vi ON tbl_wz.IDWZ = tbl_vi.VIWZID WHERE wz_stand='0' AND rep_wzrepstatus='0' ...
```

Only for the first table cars to the second one repair orders, that WHERE staement (WHERE wz_stand='0' AND rep_wzrepstatus='0') works fine.

But if i try to add the third table (VI) doing the same, i could fetch the result i wanna have.

What i wanna see in the Overview table is only the last open repair order and the last open inspection order.